# Keeping xml instance and schema namespaces appart

Tags: xml, xsd

Whenever I create a definition in a `xsd` file, `targetNamespace` appears to be the namespace for the definition names, so references are made through this namespace (using an appropriate prefix if necessary).

But `targetNamespace` should be the namespace for the elements in the `XML` file to be validated. Is it possible to use different namespaces for a `XML` instance file and definitions in its schema definition document(s)?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use different namespaces for a XML instance file and
>   definitions in its schema definition document(s)?

There two key namespaces in play in an XSD:

1. **`@targetNamespace`**: Value specifies the namespace of the XML instances governed by this XSD.
2. **`http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`**: The namespace of the constructs used by XSD to specify this XML vocabulary and grammar.

These are different, so in that sense, the answer to your question is **yes**.

However, if you're asking if a value can be used for `@targetNamespace` that differs from the target namespace of the governed XML document, then the answer is **no**.